# Haman servant of Mordechai: text of document

Tags: megillat-esther, agada-stories-legends, legal-documents, slave-serve-eved-avadim, haman

The gemara in [Megillah 15](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=15&format=pdf) writes that Mordechai acquired Haman for a piece of bread. Rashi writes:

> וזה בא בפרוזבולי - מרדכי בא אליו בטענת עושר המן בא בטענת עוני שמכר המן את עצמו למרדכי קודם לכן ימים רבים בככרי לחם:

There are midrashim which explain the whole story, but in short Mordechai acquired Haman, and the midrashim say there was a shtar (legal document) written for the acquisition.

What is the text of the document that Mordechai wrote on his shoe, showing he is the master over Haman? I believe it is in [Manos Halevi](http://hebrewbooks.org/39949), but does anyone know where exactly it is?

Answer (score 4):

The source is אגדת אסתר ה׃ט. See [page 30](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/agadatester/agadatester03.pdf).

The text there is:

> אני המן האגגי עבדו של מרדכי היהודי שנמכרתי לו בככר לחם אחת

Comment: Haman wrote it in Lashon Kodesh?

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the full text in the Manos Halevi its on [passuk 5:13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39949&st=&pgnum=294) (text of document is on next page):

> My translation : "I am Haman the son of hemdasa from the linage of
>   agag,I was sent by the king Achashverosh to fight a war against the
>   city of Hindahka,the king placed me in charge of 60000 soldiers,and he
>   gave me food to support them,and he did the same for Mordichai the son
>   of Shmi (the son of Kish) from shevet Binyamin,I wasted all the
>   belongings of the king,and I did not have enough money to support the
>   troops of the king,I went to borrow from Mordichai with interest,And
>   he said to me it is not permitted to lend me with interest since esav
>   and Yaakov were brothers,I was unable to do anything until I sold
>   myself to him as a servant,and if I stopped being his servant,or even
>   I don't admit to being his servant,or I don't show up for my work as a
>   servant for one day of the week all the days of my life and my son and
>   my sons son until the end of days,or have hatred because of the the
>   sale of selling myself to him,like esav had towards Yaakov because of
>   the selling of the bechorah,then you should uproot a piece of wood
>   from my house and hang me upon it,I accept on myself, Haman the son of
>   hemdasah from the seed of agag to be the servant of Mordichai the Jew
>   like all that i have written in this letter,With my own will, and my
>   wanting."

(If I made a mistake please correct )